# steps to replace a hadoop namenodes and journal nodes

Tags: hadoop

Setup: we have 3 machines: m1, m2 and m3
Below are the roles on each of these machines:

```
m1: namenode (active), zookeeper, hbase master, journalnode
m2: namenode (standby), zookeeper, hbase master, journalnode
m3: zookeeper, hbase master, journalnode
```

We are using namenode HA setup with QJM

All the the three machines need to be replaced with new machines (with SSD):
new_m1, new_m2 and new_m3

```
new_m1: namenode (active), zookeeper, hbase master, journalnode
new_m2: namenode (standby), zookeeper, hbase master, journalnode
new_m3: zookeeper, hbase master, journalnode
```

The replacement will incur cluster downtime, but once the new master nodes are brought, the cluster should be able to resume its normal operations.

I need help to understand in detail, the steps needed to replace journal nodes and active + standby namenodes with new hardware, with out any data loss.

Greatly appreciate the most detailed step by step answer, thanks aton

There is no hadoop version upgrade, but this is just a in-place replacement of the hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CASE I:**

If you have installed your hadoop, hbase and zookeeper (with temp, dfs and namenode directories) under one common folder, it will be easy to backup data. Let us call this folder as **home folder** from now on. Just do this:

**1. Create home folder in new active namenode system:**

`sudo mkdir -p /path/to/home/folder`
`sudo chown -R hadoopuser:hadoopgroup /path/to/home/folder`

**2. Copy all contents of home folder(permissions preserved):**

`sudo scp -rp /path/to/home/folder/in/old/active/namenode hadoopuser@new-active-node-ip:/path/to/home/folder`

**3.** Repeat these two steps for **standby namenode** and **slave nodes**.

> **NOTE:** Create a backup of **/etc/hosts** file of each node before editing.

**4.** In order to reduce workload, rename your new nodes with same names as old ones in `/etc/hosts` file. (Give your old nodes some other names if necessary)

**5.** Start the new namenode to check if it works.

**CASE II:**

If your hadoop temp, dfs, namenode and journal directories does not belong to your home folder (i.e., you have configured these directories different from home folder), do the following:

**1. Identify directory locations:**

Find the locations of hadoop temp, dfs, namenode, journal directories in **core-site.xml** and **hdfs-site.xml**.

**2. Copy contents:**

Do ** step 1** and ** step 2** from **CASE I** for each directory to preserve the permissions.

**3.** Start the new namenode to check if it works.

Comment: first of all, thank you so much for your answer, really appreciate it :)
(for case II) for my rock solid clarification, could you, may be, (in your answer) add the property names in the core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml that hold the locations of hadoop temp, dfs, namenode, journal directories ? Are you referring to values corresponding to these property names: 'dfs.namenode.name.dir', 'dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir' and 'dfs.journalnode.edits.dir' ?

Comment: Yes. To be safe backup this directory too (if you have configured): `dfs.datanode.data.dir`. I would have mentioned the property names earlier but since you haven't mentioned which version of hadoop you were using, i have to skip it.

Comment: Backup this directory: `dfs.namenode.shared.edits.dir` if you are using shared storage. Note: If possible backup all manually configured directories.

Comment: using QJM for edits. also it is a multi-TB cluster so backing up "dfs.datanode.data.dir" is not feasible
Using CDH 5.4.0 (hadoop 2.6.0); so finally need to back up dirs corresponding to the below property names:
'dfs.namenode.name.dir', 'dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir' and 'dfs.journalnode.edits.dir'. Does that look correct ?